# mod_rewrite rule for images with query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, rewrite, regex

I'm a mod_rewrite novice and a regex noob, but here's what I want to do:

I've got a [script](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) that will re-size images on the fly. I'd like to be able to take any image file path, add a query string to it, and have it automatically sent to the script to process.

So something like:

```
from: http://mysite.com/images/logo.jpg?w=100&h=50 
to:   http://mysite.com/images/thumbs/phpThumb.php?src=logo.jpg&w=100&h=50
```

Of course, if no query string is specified, it should just point to the original file.

Using the `.htaccess` file in the /images, I've got this. But it doesn't work at all. Or at best, it break all my sites images:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*
    RewriteRule ([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$) /thumbs/phpThumb.php?src=$1 [L,QSA]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: This would probably get a higher response on stackoverflow

Comment: Actually did a quick search, and found more mod_rewrite discussion here. Besides, I got the answer I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** add a **RewriteBase**, this will strip the `/images/` part in the query string. You will get `photo.jpg?w=...` instead of `/images/photo.jpg?w=...`.

**Second** add `/images/` to the redirection, because your current redirection tells to go to `http://mysite.com/thumbs/phpThumbs...` instead of `http://mysite.com/images/thumbs/phpThumbs...`.

This gives something like this:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /images/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+
    RewriteRule ([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$) /images/thumbs/phpThumb.php?src=$1 [L,QSA]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you might want to change one line to:

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+

so it will match only if a query string is present

Comment: Excellent! Works great (good to know I was close). I actually used RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[wh] to limit the keys accepted, so as not to interfere with any other potential query params down the road.